# Every C program I compile have a virus

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, mingw, virus

For the last 2 days, I've been trying to solve this issue but now I'm worried, every program I compiled is tagged as a virus. I've searched for other people like me that had the same issue and listen to how they fixed it but nothing work. I've deleted MinGW 3 times, reinstalled Visual Studio Code 2 time, nothing work.

So I decided to see if it was a virus or not and if I should tell my antivirus to stop deleting it. So I created a program with this code:

```
int main(){
    int a = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

And guess what when I compile it the size is 40 ko, and I didn't import a library!
So I inspected the exe with Ghidra and Virustotal, the two conclude that my program import kernel32.dll and msvcrt.dll something that you can see that here: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/6964dd89b4921e6fd9f6449c8fc2fb39e52e556fa35910739d8d8e61870f4657/detection also 15 security vendor flagged the exe.

By the way, I'm new in C but I don't think this is normal. If someone has any solution it would be appreciated. Also I am using Gcc with MinGW. Thanks

Comment: Those are most probably false positives. You can try getting a more up-to-date MinGW to see if it makes things better (e.g. from MSYS2). *"my program import kernel32.dll and msvcrt.dll"* This is normal.

Comment: Use an [Online Disassembler](https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) to check the .exe and look at the assembly code generated if you suspect something in the OS is changing it during the build process.

Comment: "15 security vendor flagged the exe." They will, and report on all kinds of junk files in order to alarm and sell their product.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this reassures me a bit so I'll just allow the program to execute.

Comment: Truth to be told, it could be possible that your computer does in fact have a virus on it, and newly created executables got it embedded. One thing I would suggest is to ask one of your friends to compile the same code and check the resulting executable. However, it is more likely that the stupid "antivirus" software is just giving you junk.

Comment: When I put all my stuff on a new machine, Windows Defender kindly removed all my own executables, for my safety, without warning.

Comment: Yea I've looked into the program and it look like all that is added is some MinGW things so I guess it's must be my antivirus that is weird.